# Safely cleaning up .eclipse folder

Tags: eclipse

Over the course of several years of development, my `.eclipse` folder has grown to over 1.3 GB and 33k files, so I would like to clean it up. There does not appear to be any Eclipse built-in way to do it (the `-clean` option at startup seems to have no effect on the folder).

In the folder, I see sub-folders from various versions of Eclipse I used:

```
org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_1433552022
org.eclipse.platform_4.3.2_1308942459_win32_win32_x86_64
org.eclipse.platform_4.4.2_1308942459_win32_win32_x86_64
org.eclipse.platform_4.5.2_1758890626_win32_win32_x86_64
org.eclipse.platform_4.6.2_1758889665_win32_win32_x86_64
org.eclipse.platform_4.7.0_920333535_win32_win32_x86_64 <-- current version
```

I also see some folders dated several years back that look like artifacts from old versions:

```
1069493093
1604054904
```

Also, this folder that holds just one file (`anonymousId`):

```
org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri
```

This folder contains 8 files and seems to be setup-related (hence, of one-time use?):

```
org.eclipse.oomph.setup
```

Finally, there is this older folder that contains 29 files:

```
org.eclipse.recommenders.models.rcp
```

Could any of these old folders, some of which contain up to 10k files, be safely deleted without affecting the operation of the current Eclipse version?